# A more efficient way to get an item inside of an array than Array.prototype.find()

Tags: javascript, arrays, big-o

I'm getting a `cities` array of around 1500 elements.

I'm looping to get a specific city:

```
cities.find(city => city.name === currentAddress.city.name)
```

Which is `O(n)`

Is there a more efficient way to do so than go through all 1500 elements every time?

Comment: if you are doing it repeatedly, you could set up indexing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find() will break when it encounters a match. So it really boils down to how often you need to do this search. If you do it a lot , create a hashmap using city names as keys to allow an O(1) lookup. You can use a regular object or a Map

```
const cityMap = new Map(cities.map(city => ([city.name, city]));
```

Usage:

```
// returns undefined or city object
const cityDetails = cityMap.get(currentAddress.city.name)
```

Comment: From what I get in this solution, in the creation of the map I loop through the array one time to map it to a more efficient data structure, and than use the map to find the element in O(1) every time?